# PyBind11: boost::multiprecision::cpp_int to Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, casting, pybind11

I am interested in using [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to optimize some Python computation using C++. The [casting documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/index.html) doesn't make much sense to me and was wondering if anyone knew how to cast boost datatypes, specifically cpp_int, to a Python datatype so I can return computations. A simple example of what I'm trying to do would be factorials:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>


using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
namespace py = pybind11;

py::int_ fact(int i) {
    cpp_int prod = 1;
    while(i-- >= 1){
        prod *= (i+1);
    }
    return py::cast(prod);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(fact, m) {
  m.def("fact", &fact,R"pbdoc(
        Returns the factorial of a number.
    )pbdoc");
}
```

The above compiles but when I go to use it I get

```
TypeError: Unregistered type : boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0u, 0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)1, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >, (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)1>
```

so something isn't working with py::cast I think...
 My laptop runs Windows 10 and I am using Anaconda Python 3.7

```
C:\Users\15734>python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

and [Stephan T. Lavavej's MinGW C++ 8.2.0](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

```
C:\Users\15734>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --with-tune=haswell --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)
```

I am also using [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) for the vcruntime140.dll located in "**C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MicrosoftVisualStudio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\onecore\x64\Microsoft.VC141.CRT**" (which I copied and pasted into "**C:\MinGW\lib**"). I also changed all string "gcc" in "**C:\Anaconda3\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py**" to "g++" (I *did not* change the variable names with gcc in them).

Keywords:
"pybind11" ; "Boost" ; "C++ and Python" ; "boost::multiprecision::cpp_int"

Comment: cpp_int (for some backends) is just a wrapper around a C library (mpz, maybe?) So it might be easier just to wrap the C directly.

Comment: @user14717 If I wrapped mpz how would I use it in C++ and return it via pybind11?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't use it in C++ at all. If you need to use it in both C++ and Python, my suggestion won't work.

Comment: If you go directly from C->Python, you'd build a python extension module.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html

Comment: @user14717 Do you know of any good resources for the C extension module?

Comment: I think the Python mpmath is already a C wrapper.

Comment: Maybe you can try to replace [`struct inty`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/custom.html) with `cpp_int`?. You could convert cpp_int to base16 string and pass it to [PyLong_FromString](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromString) to convert from C++-->Python, and Python-->C++ by casting PyNumber to string base16 with [PyNumber_ToBase](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html?highlight=pynumber_long#c.PyNumber_ToBase) and construct a cpp_int based on this Python string object.

Comment: @tntxtnt Does boost come with a cpp_int to base16 converter? I failed to find a converter via Google...

Comment: You could use ostringstream oss and iomanip to output cpp_int as hex `oss << std::hex << bigint` then get its `oss.str()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this working:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <sstream>

using cpp_int = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
namespace py = pybind11;

namespace pybind11
{
namespace detail
{
    template <>
    struct type_caster<cpp_int> {
        /**
         * This macro establishes the name 'cpp_int' in
         * function signatures and declares a local variable
         * 'value' of type cpp_int
         */
        PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(cpp_int, _("cpp_int"));

        /**
         * Conversion part 1 (Python->C++): convert a PyObject into a cpp_int
         * instance or return false upon failure. The second argument
         * indicates whether implicit conversions should be applied.
         */
        bool load(handle src, bool)
        {
            // Convert into base 16 string (PyNumber_ToBase prepend '0x')
            PyObject* tmp = PyNumber_ToBase(src.ptr(), 16);
            if (!tmp) return false;

            std::string s = py::cast<std::string>(tmp);
            value = cpp_int{s}; // explicit cast from string to cpp_int,
                                // don't need a base here because
                                // `PyNumber_ToBase` already prepended '0x'
            Py_DECREF(tmp);

            /* Ensure return code was OK (to avoid out-of-range errors etc) */
            return !PyErr_Occurred();
        }

        /**
         * Conversion part 2 (C++ -> Python): convert an cpp_int instance into
         * a Python object. The second and third arguments are used to
         * indicate the return value policy and parent object (for
         * ``return_value_policy::reference_internal``) and are generally
         * ignored by implicit casters.
         */
        static handle cast(const cpp_int& src, return_value_policy, handle)
        {
            // Convert cpp_int to base 16 string
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << std::hex << src;
            return PyLong_FromString(oss.str().c_str(), nullptr, 16);
        }
    };
} // namespace detail
} // namespace pybind11

py::int_ fact(int i)
{
    cpp_int prod = 1;
    while (i-- > 1) prod *= i + 1;
    return py::cast(prod);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(python_example, m)
{
    m.def("fact", &fact, R"pbdoc(
        Returns the factorial of a number.
    )pbdoc");
}
```

Probably not the fastest way since it converts `cpp_int` to a temporary base 16 string first and then convert this string to Python integer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Worked out some further improvements, but could only have done this with your snippet to start from. Let me know if you see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Though @tnt's answer works for the given example, there are two improvements possible. Firstly, it does not work for negative numbers since `cpp_int` cannot parse or output hex representations of negative numbers. Secondly, we can detect the common case where the int fits in a long long and apply the builtin conversions.

The following code addresses both issues:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <sstream>

using cpp_int = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
namespace py = pybind11;

namespace pybind11 {
namespace detail {
template <>
struct type_caster<cpp_int> {
  /**
   * This macro establishes the name 'cpp_int' in function signatures and 
   * declares a local variable 'value' of type cpp_int
   */
  PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(cpp_int, _("cpp_int"));

  /**
   * Conversion part 1 (Python->C++): convert a PyObject into a cpp_int 
   * instance or return false upon failure. The second argument indicates 
   * whether implicit conversions should be applied.
   */
  bool load(handle src, bool) {
    // First try to convert the input to a long long
    int overflow = 0;
    value = PyLong_AsLongLongAndOverflow(src.ptr(), &overflow);
    if (overflow == 0) {
      // No overflow! Just ensure return code was OK
      return !PyErr_Occurred();
    }

    // Convert into base 16 string (PyNumber_ToBase prepends '0x')
    PyObject* tmp = PyNumber_ToBase(src.ptr(), 16);
    if (!tmp) return false;

    // explicit cast from string to cpp_int, don't need a base here because
    // `PyNumber_ToBase` already prepended '0x'
    std::string hex = py::cast<std::string>(tmp);
    Py_DECREF(tmp);
    if(!hex.empty() && hex[0]=='-'){
      // cpp_int does not like negative hex strings
      value = -cpp_int{hex.c_str()+1};
    }else{
      value = cpp_int{hex};
    }

    // Ensure return code was OK (to avoid out-of-range errors etc)
    return !PyErr_Occurred();
  }

  /**
   * Conversion part 2 (C++ -> Python): convert an cpp_int instance into a 
   * Python object. The second and third arguments are used to indicate the 
   * return value policy and parent object (for 
   * ``return_value_policy::reference_internal``) and are generally ignored 
   * by implicit casters.
   */
  static handle cast(const cpp_int& src, return_value_policy, handle) {
    // First try to use the builtin long long conversion
    if (src <= std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() && 
        src >= std::numeric_limits<long long>::min()) {
      return PyLong_FromLongLong(static_cast<long long>(src));
    }

    // Otherwise convert cpp_int to base 16 string
    std::ostringstream oss;
    if (src < 0) {
      // cpp_int does not like negative hex strings
      oss << '-' << std::hex << -src;  
    } else {
      oss << std::hex << src;  
    }
    return PyLong_FromString(oss.str().c_str(), nullptr, 16);
  }
};
}  // namespace detail
}  // namespace pybind11
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0u, 0u,...` is wrong, you just defined a 0 digit min/max number type.
Further it seem cpp_int only [parse from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120029/boostmultiprecisioncpp-int-acting-like-unsigned-long-long) which is rather logical for a multiprecision number.