# Pybind11 and Boost from C++

Tags: c++, boost, pybind11

I want to use functions from Boost C++ Libraries (like gauss_kronrod.hpp) in my Pybind11 project to optimize python using C++.

Using C++ functions from standard libraries (like numeric) is straightforward:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <numeric>
namespace py = pybind11;
.
.
.
PYBIND11_MODULE(_test, m) {
    m.def("test_func", &test_func);
}
```

How can I access all the functions from Boost? I downloaded it and saved it in the folder thirdparty of my Pybind11 project. I can include a single function from Boost using to complete path to this function:

`# include <thirdparty/boost/boost/math/quadrature/gauss_kronrod.hpp>`

However func.hpp loads other functions from Boost which can not be found. I feel like I need to add the Path to Boost in my file CMakeLists.txt.

Under [PyBind11: boost::multiprecision::cpp_int to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738011/pybind11-boostmultiprecisioncpp-int-to-python) is an example where cpp_int.hpp from Boost was successfully used within Pybind11. Unfortunately, its not clear how they made the command

`#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>`

work properly

Comment: If when you downloaded it, you downloaded the repo including its CMakeLists.txt file, I believe in your cmake config, you can do something like `add_subdirectory(thirdparty/boost)`, and then do your usual `target_link_libraries(your_library Boost::boost)`

Comment: Apparently there is no CMakeLists.txt. But your comment made me realize how search for an answer to my question. Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake

Comment: please note that the answer in that thread that most aligns with modern best-practice at this time is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885372/11107541. the higher voted answers are older / out of date. I do wonder if they will work for you, since you seem to have done some interesting thirdparty thing. You may be interested in using a package/dependency manager like vcpkg or conan (or maybe CPM).